# Convertion of Geotiff from EU-DEM EPSG:3035 - ETRS89 / ETRS-LAEA to WGS84

Tags: geotiff-tiff, wgs84

I have downloaded elevation data from [EU-DEM](https://land.copernicus.eu/pan-european/satellite-derived-products/eu-dem/eu-dem-v1.1/view)

My background is in software engineering and my GIS skills are limited.

How can I convert the aforementioned geotiff to WGS84 format geotiff with lon/lat values and altitude in meters.

I tried using QGIS "called warp command from the menu on the original file" however the converted lon/lat don't match with i.e. google earth as well as the altitude values definitely are not in meters.

Expanding my workflow as requested:

Ultimately I want to import and display elevation and other GIS data in an application made in Unity3D. My working environment is Windows.

The steps I followed are:

- Convert specifically the "eu_dem_v11_E50N10.tif" (roughly the area convering Greece) file from QGIS with warp with the following settings:

  Source CRS: empty

  Target CRS: EPSG:4326 - WGS 84

  No data value: default 0.0000

  Output file res: default 0.0000

  Resampling: Nearest neighbour

  Advanced params: default

  Output data: float32

  Georeferenced extends: default

  CRS of the target raster: default

  Reprojected: c:\temp\eu_dem_wgs84.tif
- Tried to read the file and display the elevation in a Terrain object within a Unity3D project using the library [libtiff.net](https://bitmiracle.com/libtiff/) (*Maybe here is the problem as I cannot read the heights correctly*)

First issue is that, from my inexperience with QGIS, I did not find a way to find the altitude within QGIS of a lon/lat point.

Second issue is that using the gdalinfo on the generated file, the origin(lon/lat) is  wrong as in the original the origin is located north of Brindisi in Italy whereas in the converted the origin is located roughly between Bari and Taranto, resulting in reading wrong altitudes

Comment: can you expand on what you did, what settings did you pick?  I just experimented on one of the tiles and it looks fine to me. Did you save the warped raster?

Comment: Why do you need to convert it? You can have data in different CRS combined in QGIS.